# How does mobizen record internal audio on samsung

Tags: android, audio

I understand Android doesn't allow internal audio to be recorded. but on LG and Samsung it seems possible as Mobizen app can do. from developing side, what's the method used to capture internal sound?

I found similar question but it was for older version of android and about screen recording. but right now. there are a lot of screen recorders. only mobizen can record internal audio on samsung using some sort of wizard before recording start it shows a popup and says OK then recording starts with audio

Comment: what do you mean by internal audio ?

Comment: I mean it can record internal audio without listening to external mic unlike many other apps that can only record from mic.  as far as I know only mobizen and on samsung and lg can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like Android ROMs on LG and Samsung have an undocumented API for recording audio output.

Since most LG and Samsung devices sport modified versions of the Android framework, it's possible that the API has been exposed for use but not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that Mobizen made a deal specifically with Samsung and LG who allowed them to use some undisclosed API which made recording audio possible but only for Mobizen application package name and signature and maybe with some other safety restrictions. You could theoretically try to discover how it's done by decompiling the Mobizen app but keep in mind the EULA and legal considerations of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bypass hacking. Try to create C library (NDK) which take access to MIC(Hardware).